# byte[] Encoding

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8

I receive an input of a byte[].

the byte[] holds an xml.

**The xml decleration says that the encoding of the document is "Cp1255", but i suspect it is not!**

**What way do you suggest to check what is the actual encoding of the byte[]?**

I can test it manually but that is not so good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've bookmarked these pages some time ago, maybe they will be useful for you:

- [Detect character encoding](http://www.ahristov.com/tutorial/Java+Short+Recipes/Detect-character-encoding.html)
- [How to auto-detect a file's encoding](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/I18N/Howtoautodetectafilesencoding.htm)